# Wpf DatePicker DisplayDateStart must be first day of two years ago

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

Today is **15 October 2018**

myDatePicker starts with **15 October 2016** if I run following code;

```
myDatePicker.DisplayDateStart = System.DateTime.Today.AddYears(-2)
```

I want myDatePicker starts with **01 January 2016**. So the first day of the year two years ago.

Any suggestions?

Comment: C# or VB.NET?   WPF or XAML ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
myDatePicker.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime((DateTime.Now.Year - 2), 1, 1);
```

Comment: Replace 2016 with (DateTime.Today.Year - 2) and you should be fine.